# Selecting specific data containing specific characters in R (To create another variable)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with time frames:

```
df <- data.frame(start_time = c("30.06.18 19:03", "07.09.19 14:20", "15.06.18 10:42"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to create another variable that signifies whether it is 2018 or 2019 (with 1 = 2018 & 2 = 2019). I tried...

```
df$Time <- ifelse(df %>% select(start_time:c(contains(".18"))), 1,
                  ifelse(df %>% select(start_time:c(contains(".19"))), 2, 0))
```

but I found out that [selection helpers apparently only work to selection variables](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html). So I'm a bit lost as to what to do.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I encourage you to use the package **lubridate** whenever you're dealing with date. The function lubridate::year(start_time) will get the year automatically, and it will be easier to create another variable :
`data %>% mutate(new_column = ifelse(year(start_time)==2018,1,2)`

Edit : you might have to remap the data format to make this work, but lubridate has functions to convert the data to date-time (`ymd_hms()`)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about this!

Comment: Here's the link to the package cheatsheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ifelse(substr(df$start_time,8,8) == 8,1,2)
[1] 1 2 1

df$Time <- ifelse(substr(df$start_time,8,8) == 8,1,2)
df
      start_time Time
1 30.06.18 19:03    1
2 07.09.19 14:20    2
3 15.06.18 10:42    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @MonJeanJean & @Karthik answered, I also found out I could use the `grepl` function to select specific strings of a character vector.

Anyway, to answer my own question using `grepl`,

```
df$Time <- ifelse(grepl(".18", df$start_time), 1,
                  ifelse(grepl(".19", df$start_time), 2, 0))
```

Comment: **grepl** and **stringr** are indeed the best packages to handle sub-string research and modification.